# 'deleteDb' is not exported by node_modules\idb\build\idb.js error when trying to import firebase to sapper project

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, sapper

I have stumbled across this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315901/how-to-import-firebase-only-on-client-in-sapper) and tried proposed solution and it partialy worked for me.

Firebase loads fine, no error. idb doesn't load and 'npm run dev' throws me this error:

```
✗ client
'deleteDb' is not exported by node_modules\idb\build\idb.js
4: import { __values, __spread, __awaiter, __generator, __assign } from 'tslib';
5: import { ErrorFactory } from '@firebase/util';
6: import { deleteDb, openDb } from 'idb';
            ^
7:
8: /**
```

I have this in my rollup.config.js:

```
commonjs({
                namedExports: {
                    // left-hand side can be an absolute path, a path
                    // relative to the current directory, or the name
                    // of a module in node_modules
                    'node_modules/idb/build/idb.js': ['deleteDb', 'openDb'],
                    'idb': ['deleteDb', 'openDb'],
                    'node_modules/firebase/dist/index.cjs.js': ['initializeApp', 'firestore', 'auth', 'analytics' ],
                    'node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js': ['initializeApp', 'firestore', 'auth', 'analytics' ],
                    //'node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js': [],
                    //'node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/index.cjs.js': ['auth'],
                    //'node_modules/firebase/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js': ['analytics']
                },
            })
```

EDIT:
I've found out that reverting firebase from version 7.7.0 to 6.5.0 has solved this problem. Although this is not a fix I would want but will work for now.

Comment: This could happen if you are importing from a wrong package, or it is not exported from that module you are trying to import.

Comment: This import must be a part of firebase's package, i'm not making this import...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?