# sapper with firebase - fetch not defined

Tags: firebase, svelte, svelte-3, sapper, rxfire

I am getting this error when running `npm run dev`

```
registerFunctions(firebase$1, fetch.bind(self));
                              ^
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

I figured **rxfire** doesn't import fetch, so I add this line to **src/server.ts**

```js
global['fetch'] = require('node-fetch');
```

And the error is still there, any suggestions?  I would think I would not have to add this at all.

I am just using **rxfire** in a **src/firebase.ts** file like so:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/functions"; 
import * as config from "./config.json";

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export const db = firebase.firestore();
export const functions = firebase.functions();
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: Put a more complete code, where we can see where is that code, what file, and what does it do?

Comment: see updated code, I am simply using firebase with sapper, not much to it

Answer (score 0):

This was a specific error caused when trying to `import "firebase/functions"` on the server end in my **firebase.ts** file.

I was able to solve it by adding `import 'isomorphic-unfetch'` to **server.ts**. However, then I got this error:

```
registerFunctions(firebase$1, fetch.bind(self));
                                         ^

ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

I realized there apparently is no object to bind to on the backend, so I found a work around. I needed to not import it on the backend, which was a bigger Sapper Firebase problem.

See [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66202819/271450) for complete fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with this error stacktrace :

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (/var/task/webpack:/Users/dev/projects/node_modules/@firebase/functions/dist/index.esm.js:702:27)
at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
at /var/task/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:83:1
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/families.js:87:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
at Module._require.i.require (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:73397)
```

I solve it by updating the firebase import to

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Answer (score 0):

first install `whatwg-fetch`.

`npm i --save whatwg-fetch` `yarn add --save whatwg-fetch`  `pnpm i --save whatwg-fetch`

create a file `./define-self.js`

with this content

```js
var global =
  (typeof globalThis !== "undefined" && globalThis) ||
  (typeof self !== "undefined" && self) ||
  (typeof global !== "undefined" && global);

if (!global?.self) {
  global.self = global;
}
```

on your index.svelte / _layout.svelte

```html
<script context="module">
  import "./define-self";
  import "whatwg-fetch";
</script>
```